# Why is using super to call methods other than the one being overridden not recommended?

Tags: java, inheritance

In oracle tutorial, it says:
If your method overrides one of its superclass's methods, you can invoke the **overridden** method through the use of the keyword super.

It mentioned about the use of super in overridden method.

However, I reality, in the sample program I wrote, I can use super keywords to access **any** method in the superclass.

The question here is: why most people talking online about the use of super, they always talking about the invocation of overridding method?

I mean, why that "use super to call other method in superclass" is not recommended?

---

BTW, one more question here:
we can't use super in static method. The compiler won't let us do that.

Is it because the variable "super" belongs to an object instead of the class, just like keyword "this"?. A static method belongs to a class, and the static method doesn't **have** the variable "super"?

Comment: It strikes me as a little weird and confusing enough to cause problems. I can't think of a specific reason it's bad practice. What I would recommmend is pay attention to when you need it, then work out that exact design problem there - or post that design problem to SO, explain Oracle doc frowns upon the practice and ask why it's bad in your case.

Comment: It suggests the old method is still needed, in which case you probably shouldn't be overriding it in the first place (the old method still "makes sense" within the child object"). Two identically named methods both being used within the same object but with different effects sounds like a nightmare

Comment: @RichardTingle It means the super's method does something different from the child method, and both are needed. Therefore they should have different names. I think that's the only good answer so far. Would you mind posting it?

Comment: @djechlin done: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23878740/2187042

Comment: Stack overflow questions work best with one question per post. But I've tried to edit in an answer to your second question within my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Why using super.foo() outside method foo() is a bad idea

It suggests the old method is still needed (and does something different from the child version of the method), in which case you probably shouldn't be overriding it in the first place. The parent method still "makes sense" within the child object.

Two identically named methods both being used within the same object but with different effects sounds like a nightmare for readability. Given that both are being used it seems highly likely that they should be separate methods with different method names making their subtle difference clear.

## Why using super.foo() to refer to a method that isn't overridden is a bad idea

This semantically is a very odd thing to write. A parents (non private) methods **are** the childs methods unless overridden, using `super.method()` has an identical effect to `method()` and so it is not surprising you have not seen this mentioned. As you have supposed it is also very likely to cause bugs in the future if you later do override the method.

Similarly to this you can put `public` on the front of interface methods but it has no effect.

## Why you can't use super with static methods

Static methods cannot be overridden, if a parent class and a child class happen to have the same method name that is simply a coincidence as far as the compiler is concerned (although it does *hide* the static method in the parent class - it does not override it).  Given that a static method cannot be overridden using the `super` keyword to access one becomes meaningless. Furthermore you can access a static method in Foo as

`Foo.staticMethod();`

Comment: c.f. this overriding super, in which it encapsulates the old behavior and doesn't expose it through the rest of the class, which is consistent with the recommendation.

Comment: Static method can't be overridden. True. If, I mean, if the keyword super can only be used in an overridden method, then using super in static method because meaningless. However, we can use super to call any method in the super class(Which I think should be a bad idea, that's why I'm asking here). It means that its not mandatory to use super in overridden method. This undermine the claim that: " Given that a static method cannot be overridden using the super keyword to access one becomes meaningless". I'm not very good at English, I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: @FanZhang Ah, I think I understand what you mean now, I've added a section in my answer to try to address that. Arguably the syntax to access a static method in annother class is `Foo.staticMethod();`. This is different from a non static method where the specific inheritance chain is important so allowing `super` would be less clear

Comment: @RichardTingle Thank you for the detailed explanation. One more question here: Let's say class A has a static method SMA() and class B extends class A and has another static method SMB(). SMB() is just a static class defined in class B, not inherited from A. Clearly, I can use A.SMA() in method SMB(). But what prevent me from using super.SMA() in method SMB()?

Comment: @FanZhang Ultimately its just a design decision made by the designers of the java language. But it makes sense to me for `super.SMA()` not to be available since its a more roundabout way of calling a static method in another class. The class hierarchy is far less important to the static parts of a class; which the absence of `super` references to static methods reinforces (in fact I can only think of 1, very minor, way in which the child class cares about the static parts of its parent class at all).

Answer (score 2):

> However, I reality, in the sample program I wrote, I can use super keywords to access any method in superclass.

In the *real* reality you can't ... except in very specific circumstances.

You can't use `super` to call a method that is forbidden by the access rules:

- Calling a `private` method is forbidden unless this class is nested within the other or vice versa.
- Calling a package private method is forbidden unless this class is in the same package as the other.
- Calling a `protected` method is allowed.

If you have an example that appears to contradict this, please add it to your Question so that we can explain what is actually going on.

> The question here is: why most people talking online about the use of super, they always talking about the invocation of overridding method?

I think you may be talking about this:

```
public class A {
    public void foo() {...}
}

public class B extends A {
    public void foo() {   // The overriding method.
        ...
        super.foo();      // invoking the overridden method.
        ...
    }
}
```

The method in the child class invokes the overridden version of itself.  The reason that you are seeing it in lots of example is that it is *the most common* use-case for `super`.  That's all.

On the other hand if the method `A.foo()` is not overridden at all, then it is legal to use `super.foo()` to call it in `B` ... but I don't think it is good style.  For a start, it would probably break if you then *did* add an override method in `B`.

Comment: What's wrong with the example where the derived class is calling a method permitted by the access rules, in the parent and not in the grandfather? I don't really see how your answer adds value...

Comment: I understand that I can't call the "grandfather". However, that's not my question. ty.

Comment: @FanZhang - Arguably that >>is<< your Question.  The problem is in the grammar of your Question.  You said *"... in superclass"*, which could mean either *"... in THE superclass"* or *"... in A superclass"*.  The latter meaning would refer to *any* superclasses.  You need to read up on the use of prepositions in English.

Comment: @StephenC oh, thank you. I mean "the superclass". :)

Comment: Just want to note that I understood this clearly despite the grammatical ambiguity. Even fluent Chinese, Japanese, etc. ESL speakers often don't grasp that point since it's lacking in their languages, and the correct thing to do if you felt the difference was crucial was to add a comment (or check the referred Oracle docs.)

Comment: @djechlin - I didn't originally see the ambiguity.  I simply read it the other way.  And I still think that the other reading was valid and meaningful.  That's the whole problem with ambiguity.  But beating up on someone because they picked the wrong meaning out of two plausible meanings is ... unreasonable.

Comment: @djechlin - What "referred docs" are you talking about?  The OP did not refer to any docs.  And they are not relevant to the ambiguity of the Question.

Comment: @djchlin - *"What's wrong with the example where the derived class is calling a method permitted by the access rules, in the parent and not in the grandfather?"*.  Nothing.  But that's not what the Question says.  The Question says "any method".  In fact, the "any" is in **bold** ... which most people would read as emphasising the generality / lack of qualification.

Answer (score 1):

`super.f()` bypasses `this.f()`. If there is no implementation `this.f()`  then `super` is not needed. Otherwise there is a bit of code smell when not called inside `this.f()`.

In short: one cannot find many sensible usages for `g()` calling `super.f()`: it provides no solution for any known problem.

I could only think of the following: a layouting of rectangles, by using recursively horizontally listed boxes, every box inside listing vertically listed boxes, inside listing horizontally listed boxes etc.

```
public class SpecialBoxLayout extends BoxLayout {

    @Override
    public void layoutHor(...) {
        ... // Something extra, special
        for
            super.layoutVert(...);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void layoutVert(...) {
        ...
        for
            super.layoutHor(...);
        ...
    }
```

This needs inheritance, with a method getting extra functionality, and having complementary methods. A language feature not really needed. Like the non-existing `super.super.f()`.

---

It (g calling super.f) is bad style because:

- it skips a layer of inheritance
- very rare usage
- the rare usage above could very well be rewritten parametrised as a single parametrized `layout(Orientation.VERT, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `super.method()` to call any method, but you can use `super()` only to call the overridden method.

Comment: I know~But what I'm asking is that: if I call other methods other than overridden methods, will it cause some problems? Like make the program harder to maintain?

Comment: Umm I'm not sure if it will call the method in the superclass or if it will call your method if you override the method you call...

Comment: I am pretty sure that `super()` calls the parent class's no-arg constructor, which is invalid in a method because constructors are not methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have classes A and B, where B extends A. Class A has methods: methodOne(), methodTwo() and class B overrides methodOne(). However remember that class B has also methodTwo(), since it's inherited so there is no use to call it via super because you have it directly in descendant class.

EDIT Let's take a look on that:

```
import java.util.*;
class A {
    public void methodOne() {
        System.out.println("A.1");
        methodTwo();
        //super.methodTwo(); 
            /*This above would lead to compilation error even though
            it would work as intended - always print A.2. 
            Use instead for instance: ((A)this).methodTwo();*/

    }

    public void methodTwo() {
        System.out.println("A.2");
    }
}

class B extends A{
    @Override
    public void methodTwo() {
        System.out.println("B.2");
    }
    public B() {
        methodOne();
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a.methodTwo();
        b.methodTwo();
    }
}
```

Comment: If methodOne calls methodTwo, should it call methodTwo or super.methodTwo? What if it only needs super.methodTwo?

Comment: Just give it a try! (And remember that you may cast descendant class to parent class -> that's called polymorphism)

Comment: @djechlin I think TeoTN made the point. If I inherited methodTwo() from the parent. I don't need to use super. use super.methodTwo is the same as using methodTwo.

Comment: @FanZhang they're not the same if methodTwo overrides its parent, which is what I assumed your question was about...

Comment: @djechlin yes~right~ I see. If methodTwo in the child class doesn't override, it make no difference. If methodTwo has been overridden, then, its different.

Comment: But methodOne must not call super.methodTwo, since it would not work for class A itself -> calling A.methodOne would seek for super.methodTwo in Object class. It such a case you would use casting.

Comment: @TeoTN that doesn't make any sense to me. Yes, you must avoid writing code that doesn't compile. super.methodTwo from methodOne does compile in the example you gave.